# AS3: How do declare button?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new to AS3 classes so I created a simple "project" for me to understand them better, and I have immediately run into a problem.

In my flash file, I created a button, put it on the stage and gave it an instance of HitButtonA

then in my external class file I have this code:

```
    package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class External extends MovieClip
    {

    private var counter:Number;

        public function External()
        {
         setupListeners();
         counter=0;
        }


    public function setupListeners()
    {
        HitButtonA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitButtA);
    }

    public function hitButtA()
    {
        display.text=String(++counter);
    }



    }
}
```

but when I run the flash file I get this error:

> Line 20  1120: Access of undefined property HitButtonA.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you declaring HitButtonA? You can't add an eventlistener to a class definition without initializing one. `var hitbuttunA:HitButtonA = new HitButtonA();`

Comment: I declared it in flash (http://picthost.net/v.php?id=54e618b60e16bc9e47fa438693e12dba) , do I need to declare it in two places??

Comment: You declared a Class, not an object. You use things like .addEventListener you should create a new Object of class HitButtinA just like Tobias Kun said.

And make sure your HitButtonA has a "Export for actionscript" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this code will be useful, if you are using a property from a class, then you must declare as property.

For example, put this in your class (and replace your `function` hitButtA) :

```
public function get hitButtA():void{
   return null;
}
public function set hitButtA(value:Object):void{
   display.text=String(++counter);
}
```

Note: this is an example to solve your problem, this is not a correct use for getter/setter function. Therefore, you should use a setter, for set a property from a class, for example:

```
objectFromMyClass.hitButtA = value;
```

or using a getter:

```
var value:Object = objectFromMyClass.hitButtA;
```

Check this link for more explanation **[link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=asdoc_4.html)**.

You have an error because, you must declare a **property** hitButtA in the class, so, you must declare a ***public variable*** or a ***getter/setter function***.

Comment: Im really new to this, I am not sure how to use what you wrote above... can you look at my class and tell me how and where to use it?

Comment: @Ryan i 've edited my answer with a more explanation, check that and tell me if it was useful